# Chaining a series of Promises

Tags: javascript

I need to execute a bunch of 'promisified' function sequentially (I mean synchronously, since in each one needs the result of the previous one).
This code prints `bar1bar0` while I expect `bar0bar1`.

```
function _setTime(str) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(`bar${str} `);
      }, 1);
    });
}
_setTime("0")
    .then(function(str) {
        return _setTime("1"+str)
  })
  .then(function(str) {
        console.log(str)
  })
```

Comment: What's the point of that `setTImeout`?

Comment: it's just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround:

```
 _setTime("0").then(function(str) {
    return _setTime("1").then(res=>str+res)
 })
.then(function(str) {
    console.log(str)
})
```

Comment: the whole purpose is try to find a way to keep the code clean and clear as possible, your solution works, but I prefer a way to chain the `.then()`.

Comment: @alfredopacino Chaining `.then` functions will become obsolete when [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) finally appears.

Comment: yeah, since i'm in Electron I guess I will use `await`

Answer (score 5):

The code is functioning correctly and is being handled "synchronously"... you just have a bug in how you are calling your function:

The first `setTime("0")` "returns" `"bar0"`

You then call `setTime("1" + "bar0")` which "returns" `"bar" + "1bar0"`

Your newer strings are being prepended rather appended.